# Firebase iOS: check if a user with email exists without signing out current anonymous user

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

My app automatically signs users into an anonymous account on launch. Users have the option to link their anonymous account to an email later on or sign in to an existing account.

When users attempt to sign in to an existing account, I use `Auth.signIn(withEmail:password:)`. The problem here is that this will sign the current anonymous user out, even if the passed credentials are incorrect. This will result in having the data linked to the anonymous user being lost with no way to recover it, since calling `Auth.signInAnonymously()` again will generate a new user ID.

So my question is, how can I check if the email/password a user has entered are correct without signing out of the current anonymous user?

Note that `Auth.fetchSignInMethods(forEmail:)` also results in the anonymous user getting signed out.

Comment: This sounds like it could be a bug in the SDK.  I suggest filing a bug report with Firebase support or the Firebase iOS SDK GitHub.
  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support
  https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk

Comment: Darn... I didn't know that `fetchSignInMethods(forEmail:) ` would sign the current user out. That would've been my go to method for this use-case. Without that, the only thing I can think of is [using the Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#retrieve_user_data), through Cloud Functions, to expose this functionality as a custom API to your app.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I don't see any way with the admin SDK to verify a user/password combination.

Comment: @DougStevenson I thought this is working as designed, but after checking the docs again, this behavior isn't mentioned anywhere, so yeah it might be a bug. Will open a GitHub issue.

Comment: You have to `link` the `Anonymous User Account` with `Email` account and then it will be converted to `Email` account.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I am unable to duplicate that behavior. I have anonymous authentication turned on and automatically log in to firebase at app start. If I then try to authenticate with email and password and say, I use the wrong password so it fails, it doesn't log out the anonymous user. A simple test of `print(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid)` after logging in anonymously and then using the print command again after `Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: user, password: pw` fails shows the same uid as it did when first logging in. Maybe I misunderstand the question?

Comment: Also, I am not having any issues with `Auth.auth().fetchSignInMethods(` logging the anonymous user out either. At login I use this `Auth.auth().signInAnonymously() { (auth, error) in` then I have a button that prints the anonymous uid to console. I then have a button that runs this `Auth.auth().fetchSignInMethods(forEmail: user` with user = some email address. I run the fetchSign in code and afterwords print the uid to console and it's the same uid as it was initially.

Comment: Thanks Jay! @HeshamAbd-Elmegid Please edit your question to include the exact code and steps that anyone can take to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Jay you did understand the question correctly and you're absolutely right, this isn't a Firebase issue. Your comment let me to do more debugging and turns out that a `stateDidChangeListener` was incorrectly reacting to the authentication change and calling `signOut`. The issue is fixed now.Thanks!